# How to constrain the width and height of <Border> element to be equal to its inner contents?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight-4.0

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Grid Name="detailGrid">
```

Here, the `detailGrid` and its `border` takes complete Width and Height, as available from the outer `mainGrid`, where as the contents inside the `detailGrid` are having  Width and Height that is much much lesser.

How can I constrain the Width and Height of `Border` or/and `detailGrid` to fit to its contents, so the the Outer Grid's background is visible ?

Comment: try moving border element under detailgrid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the border and the inner grid `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Center`.
(or just the border should do it)

Comment: Damn, I should have known that :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your user control has defined `Height` and `Width` properties remove them.

Then define `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` for your `Grid` and set their `Height` And `Width` to `Auto`.